# Zoom in on array of locations

Tags: javascript, view, bing-maps

I am facing some minor issues regarding setting the optimal view on bing maps.

I already found some solutions in the internet but unfortunately none of them are working for me.
My bing map is displaying multiple addresses which is working fine and now I want to adjust the view, so that my map is zooming in on my pushpins.

The following is my source code:

```
function addData(locationInput){
         counter = 0;
         var locationSet = locationInput.split("#");
         //Array from Locations 
         var locs = new Array();
         for(var i = 0; i < locationInput.length; i++){
           if(i == 0){
              locationSet[0] = locationSet[0].substr(1);
           }
           var locSet = locationSet[i].split(";");
           var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(locSet[0], locSet[1]);
           locs.push(location);
           var pushpin=new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location,{text:counter.toString()});
           map.entities.push(pushpin);
           counter++; 
           console.log(this);
         }
         //Set view boundaries
         map.setView({bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs)});
     }
```

Comment: Are the pushpins properly displayed on the map?

Comment: Yes, they are properly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate a LocationRect from your locations it will be tight to the coordinates and does not account for the size of your pushpin icon. You set the view set a padding value to account for this. Try this:

```
 map.setView({bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs), padding: 100});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately your provided code isn't working neither.

Comment: It should. I use this all the time. Try a larger padding value if you have bigger pushpin icons.

Answer (score 0):

Since map.setview is async, views are not loaded properly sometimes. Adding a delay to it solves the issue for me.

```
setTimeout((function () {
                map.setView({bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs)});
            }).bind(this), 1500);
```